# I can't get my footer to stay at the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm new at this. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried both the absolute and relative position but I can't get the footer to go at the bottom of the page. I also don't want the fixed option. Can anyone tell what's wrong with it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>after hours</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="banner">

        <div class="content">
            <h1>as always <br> at this hour </h1> 
            <h1 class="maroon">time means <br> nothing</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <a href="home.html">home</a>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
        <a href="blog.html">blog</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
    </div>  

    <div id="main">

        <div class="about">
            <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>

            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This is a rectangle.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This is a rectangle too.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This a rectangle as well.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <footer>
    <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>
    </footer> 

</body>

</html>
```

This is the separate CSS code. I'm not sure if the footer should be a class or it can simply be a tag.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

#banner {
    background: url(imgs/1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 660px;
    position: absolute;
}

#banner .content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 42.6%;
    padding: 30 30 60 30;
    color: #d6d6d6;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: futura;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;

    /*
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    width: 260px;
    height: 80px;
    */
}

#banner .content h1.maroon {
    padding-top: 70px;
    color: firebrick;
}

.nav { 
    position: relative;
    top: 660px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.nav a {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 22px 40px;
    display: inline;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: firebrick;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 670px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.about {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;

}

.rectangle {
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 180px;
    height: 200px;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want a fixed footer then you need enough content to push it to the bottom. How ever there are a few tricks to force it.

Comment: Add css of your code,

Comment: you could set a `min-height` on the main wrapper .. You could also use `jQuery` to force it to the bottom after page load ..

Comment: We'd need to see your CSS, however as Coffee bean said, if there's not enough content to fill a screen then the footer won't sit on the bottom. You could get around this by adding a min-height to your page body, or by using calc(100vh - footer height) to absolutely position the footer at the bottom.

Comment: Your footer markup is invalid also: `<div class="footer"></footer>` ... should be `<footer></footer>` to match your css styles

Comment: @zgood Oh sorry. I've been trying and switching from footer tag to footer class. But even if I change it, the footer still stays at the banner part. I'm not sure why..

Comment: You can either use a `<footer>` tag with a `footer {}` in the CSS, or a `<div class="footer">` with `.footer {}` in the CSS, but you're mixing both in your sample code, which won't work.

Comment: @Coffeebean Can I ask why it has to be "forced"? Why can't I simply use absolute and relative? I've tried creating a test html file that only has banner, content, and footer with absolute, relative, and absolute positions respectively and they work just fine. Is it because there are many conflicting elements?

Comment: @delinear I've already tried changing it to the <footer> tag . I forgot to switch it back since I've been trying between the footer class and tag because I thought that was the problem. But even then it still won't work..

Comment: @Lois when I say force it I mean put it there non relatively which would be the natural flow of a modern web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position everything relative, unless you really need to use absolute.
See working snippet using your code.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    position: relative;
}

#banner {
    background: url(imgs/1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 660px;
    position: relative;
}

#banner .content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 42.6%;
    padding: 30 30 60 30;
    color: #d6d6d6;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: futura;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
  
}

#banner .content h1.maroon {
  position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
    color: firebrick;

}

.nav { 
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  clear: both;
}

.nav a {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 22px 40px;
    display: inline;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: firebrick;
  clear: both;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
    clear: both;
}

.about {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;

}

.rectangle {
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 180px;
    height: 200px;
}

.content {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>after hours</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="banner">

        <div class="content">
            <h1>as always <br> at this hour </h1> 
            <h1 class="maroon">time means <br> nothing</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <a href="home.html">home</a>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
        <a href="blog.html">blog</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
    </div>  

    <div id="main">

        <div class="about">
            <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>

            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This is a rectangle.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This is a rectangle too.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This a rectangle as well.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <footer>
    <p>Footer text in here</p>
    </footer> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. It also helped assigning a min-height to the #main id to keep the footer at the bottom. Last question though, I noticed you put a couple of clear: both; What does it do?

Comment: Glad it helped you :)  "clear: both" clears any floats that may be affecting the flow of elements afterwards. It basically cancels the float before your next element.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is put the div at the botton of the screen then add this to your css:

```
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

When you scroll the footer will also move though. If you want it to stay in the same location then make `position: fixed`

Comment: I've tried both absolute and relative but both options don't work. I'm not sure why... the footer text just stays at the banner position.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you are closing `</footer>` instead of close `</div>`.

And give `position: relative` to the main parent div and apply

```
 .footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
  }
```

this will work.

Comment: I've already switched it back to the <footer> tag. I've also tried both absolute and relative but both options don't work. I'm not sure why...

Comment: make fiddle of your code it will help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**remove position: relative; #main id css.**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

#banner {
    background: url(imgs/1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 660px;
    
}

#banner .content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top: 54%;
    left: 42.6%;
    padding: 30 30 60 30;
    color: #d6d6d6;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: futura;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;

    /*
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    width: 260px;
    height: 80px;
    */
}

#banner .content h1.maroon {
    padding-top: 70px;
    color: firebrick;
     position:relative;
}

.nav { 
   
    top: 660px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.nav a {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 22px 40px;
    display: inline;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: firebrick;
}

#main {
   /* position: relative;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 670px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.about {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;

}

.rectangle {
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 180px;
    height: 200px;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
}

footer {
   /* position: absolute;*/
   float: left;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>after hours</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="banner">

        <div class="content">
            <h1>as always <br> at this hour </h1> 
            <h1 class="maroon">time means <br> nothing</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <a href="home.html">home</a>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
        <a href="blog.html">blog</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
    </div>  

    <div id="main">

        <div class="about">
            <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>

            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This is a rectangle.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This is a rectangle too.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p>This a rectangle as well.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <footer>
    <p>this is footer part <br/>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>
    </footer> 

</body>

</html>
```